# Removing vowels from c string without using c string functions

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm trying to remove the vowels from the userInput array and copy the rest to the newString array. I thought looping through the userInput and assigning it to newStrin would work but im only getting the first character of newString array. I can see that on the iteration where i = 2, 't' should be assigned to newString[2] but when I attempt to print the array back in main it only prints the first character.

```
void removeVowels( char newString [], char userInput []){
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < myStrlen(userInput)) {
        if ( (userInput[i] != 'a')&&
             (userInput[i] != 'e')&&
             (userInput[i] != 'i')&&
             (userInput[i] != 'o')&&
             (userInput[i] != 'u')){
             newString[i] = userInput[i]; 
             cout << newString[i] << endl; 
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

My output:

```
c

t

cat without vowels is: c
```

---

Expected output:

```
c

t

cat without vowels is: ct
```

Comment: You need to use a separate index for the source and destination if they are going to be different lengths. You are copying non vowels but leaving the places where you have a vowel with a garbage value in the destination.

Answer (score 4):

The only part you are missing is keeping track of the place to write at

```
int writePos = 0;
```

Then, to replace `newString[i] = userInput[i];` with `newString[writePos++] = userInput[i];` which will write at the right place, then increment the position.

And then, fix the `cout` accordingly.

As @SalehMostafa points out, you should null-terminate the string, too, otherwise the caller will be reading garbage at the end.

```
newString[writePos] = 0; // at the end before returning
```

Comment: It may also be a good idea to return the length of the resulting string as well, or add a character '\0', so the end of the string is easily known.

Answer (score 1):

in Modern C++

```
string s = "my lovely cat is jumping in the kitchen again";
auto r = std::remove_if( s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto x) {
    return "aeiou"s.find(x) != std::string::npos; 
} );
s.erase(r, s.end());

[my lvly ct s jmpng n th ktchn gn]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eW89b6

Comment: Since it looks like the question puts the result in a new variable, you might want to do this with `copy_if`.